# NSURL error for broken links in Swift

Tags: macos, swift, nsurl

I coded a function for OSX 10.10 that is willing to open a text file from an URL and display its content.

Everything is working but if the URL cannot be reach then the App will crash. How could I handle this type of Error?
I guess it comes from the completionHandler closure but I am not sure.

here is my code

```
@IBAction func checkAdminMessage(sender: NSMenuItem) {


    let messageURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.xxxxxx.com/text.txt")

    // The Network stuff will be handled in a background thread
    let sharedSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask = sharedSession.downloadTaskWithURL(messageURL!,
        completionHandler: {
            (location: NSURL!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

            var urlContents = NSString(contentsOfURL: location, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)


            // Check if text.txt has NULL as content
            if urlContents! == "NULL" {


                // Have to use Grand Central Dispatch to put NSAlert in the main thread
                let noMessage = NSLocalizedString("Nothing there", comment: "Text to dislay when the file is empty" )

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
                    self.displayAlertNotification(notification: noMessage)

                }

            } else {
                // If the file is not empty then we display the content of this file
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
                    self.displayAlertNotification(notification: urlContents!)
                }

            }
    })
    downloadTask.resume()
}
```

Thank you

EDIT: Here is the updated code but the App still crashed

```
@IBAction func checkAdminMessage(sender: NSMenuItem) {

 if let messageURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.xxxxxx.com/text.txt") {
        let sharedSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()


        let downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask = sharedSession.downloadTaskWithURL(messageURL,
            completionHandler: {
                (location: NSURL!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

                var urlContents = NSString(contentsOfURL: location, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil )


                if urlContents == "NULL" {

                    println(urlContents)
                    // Have to use Grand Central Dispatch to put NSAlert in the main thread
                    let noMessage = NSLocalizedString("Nothing there", comment: "Text to dislay when the file is empty" )

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
                        self.displayAlertNotification(notification: noMessage)
                    }
                }
                else {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
                        self.displayAlertNotification(notification: urlContents!)
                    }
                }


        })
        downloadTask.resume()

    }
    else {
        println("Error")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with the helps of the people that commented my question.

I was getting a nil from 'location' in downloadTaskWithUrl, then the var urlContents was receiving a nil as well.

The solution is to check if 'location' is nil :

```
        let downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask = sharedSession.downloadTaskWithURL(messageURL,
            completionHandler: {
                (location: NSURL!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

                **if (location != nil) {**


                var urlContents = NSString(contentsOfURL: location, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil ) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSURL(string: ...)` returns an optional, so the result may be `nil` due to several reasons.

Wrap your code in a conditional unwrap:

```
if let messageURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.xxxxxx.com/text.txt") {
    // success
    ...
}
else {
   // error
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I modified my code according to your comment but the App still crash if the URL does not exist. Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. Of course I removed the ! of the optional urlContents. Any clue?

Comment: At what line does it crash?

Comment: Here var urlContents = NSString(contentsOfURL: location, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil )

Comment: `downloadTaskWithURL` provides an `error`. Did you check what's in it?

Comment: 'location' and 'response' are both nil, and 'error' give me NSError! domain: "NSURLErrorDomain".    I don't understand why it doesn't work. The first line of my code (if let messageURL = NSURL ...) should protect against bad URsL.

Comment: You are unwrapping a `nil` variable which causes the crash. Can't help you further you have to find out whats wrong with your URL. Maybe you can try the other method `downloadTaskWithURL` of `NSURLSession` to go step by step.